# "Could not load file or assembly" using COM Interop (DLL HELL?)

Tags: c#, dll, microsoft-graph-api, com-interop, powerbuilder

I'm building a COM Visible Object that needs to get called from a software written in Sybase Powerbuilder 11.5.
I'm using C# and .Net Framework 4.7.2.
I ususally build this kind of objects with no problem and register them using regasm /codebase because that's the way Powerbuilder likes them.

Now I'm trying to build an object that references the latest version of these nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Graph
Microsoft.Graph.Auth
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
Graph.Community
```

I have my class library project with a com visible class.
I built a console application that references that library (it does not use COM server) to test the code and everything works fine on my development machine from the command line.
I can also run the console application from my target machin with no issues.

When I try to run the Powerbuilder application that uses the COM object, it throws an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=1.23.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

I have that dll in assembly's folder, but it is version 1.24.0.0.
I have two questions:

1. Why does the console application work while the COM object doesn't, given that they are using the same assemblies?
2. How I solve this versioning problem in the COM version of the object?

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem. Microsoft.Graph.Core is just the name of the library, it is not a .Net Core library. It is a dependecy of Microsoft.Graph library that requires .Net Framework 4.6.1 or later

Comment: Building with 4.6.1 does not help

Comment: Sounds like a dependency issue with the libraries that you're using. Install the right dependency ones first as its needed to run(also you confirmed it works in your dev machine), install the necessary NuGet packages and try repro the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem but did not fully understand it.
It was a cross reference problem, where packages A and B were both dependent on package C, but required different versions.
I don't understand why this error shows up only when using COM Interface and not with the console application.

Here is what I did to solve:

```
// Define the AssemblyResolve event in the constructor of the COM Object.
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

// Get the path where COM Object's dll is
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
_dllPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            // Get the name of the assembly that failed loading
            var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

            // Manage the assembly that I know will cause problems
            string bindingAssembly = "Microsoft.Graph.Core";
            if (name.Name == bindingAssembly)
            {
                // Load the assembly from the COM Object's folder, and use whatever version there is
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(_dllPath, bindingAssembly + ".dll"));
            }

            // I should not get here. If I do I need to add another manual assembly load for the dll that failed loading
            return null;
        }
```